# dovecot root password

Tags: imap, squirrelmail, dovecot

I'm trying to use dovecot IMAP server, and with the interface of squirrelmail.
Correct me if i'm wrong but I understood that the root login credentials for the
squirrelmail are the same as the root login credentials for the dovecot.

If so, how can i set/configure/find out my dovecot root password?
thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "root login credentials"? I thought you meant the IMAP username and password that you use to log in to your email account (yes, that's the same) but it is very unusual to login with IMAP as root... so do you mean something else? Are you talking about logging in to administer the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dovecot is used for mail delivery and should not be confused with the server root. You set up users with passwords usually in the /etc/passwd  /etc/shadow directories.

For instance in the dovecot.conf file:

```
protocols = imap imaps
auth default {
mechanisms = plain login
passdb pam {
args = dovecot
}
userdb passwd {
}
socket listen {
client {
  path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
  user = postfix
  group = postfix
  mode = 0660
}
}
}
```

Dovecot will use PAM for password authentication and look in the /etc/passwd file for users and match them with password from either /etc/passwd or if not found there /etc/shadow

So whatever user/password combinations you create, those are the ones that can connect via IMAP from your squirrelmail interface